# How to reverse list before add to recyclerView adapter in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my application I want to use `recyclerView` to show some data from the server.

My list is:

> item1, item2, item3, item4, item5

**item1** is **oldest** and **item5** is **newest**.
I want first sort item such as `item5, item4, item3, item2, item1` then add into `adapter`.

**item1** is **oldest** and **item5** is **newest**.
I want first sort item such as `item5, item4, item3, item2, item1` then add into `adapter`.

**I fill adapter data with this code into OnResponse on Retrofit :**

```
//Comments
if (postResponse.getCommentCount() == 0) {
    detailPage_commentsSellAll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    detailPage_commentEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    detailPage_commentList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    detailPage_commentsSellAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    detailPage_commentEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    detailPage_commentList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    detailPage_commentsTitle.setText(getString(R.string.comments) + " (" + postResponse.getCommentCount() + ")");
    commentsModel.clear();
    commentsModel.addAll(postResponse.getComments());
    commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**My adapter codes:**

```
public class DetailCommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailCommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CommentsItem> model;
    private Context context;

    public DetailCommentAdapter(List<CommentsItem> model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public DetailCommentAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.detail_comment_row, viewGroup, false);
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        return new DetailCommentAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DetailCommentAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        int newPos = model.size() - 1;
        //Image
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.get(newPos).getUrl())) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(model.get(position).getUrl())
                    .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(viewHolder.detailCmRow_img) {
                        @Override
                        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                            viewHolder.detailCmRow_img.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            viewHolder.detailCmRow_img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.default_avatar));
        }
        //Name
        viewHolder.detailCmRow_name.setText(model.get(newPos).getName());
        //Date
        viewHolder.detailCmRow_date.setText(model.get(newPos).getDate());
        //Comment
        viewHolder.detailCmRow_comment.setText(Html.fromHtml(model.get(newPos).getContent()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.detailCmRow_img)
        ImageView detailCmRow_img;
        @BindView(R.id.detailCmRow_name)
        TextView detailCmRow_name;
        @BindView(R.id.detailCmRow_date)
        TextView detailCmRow_date;
        @BindView(R.id.detailCmRow_comment)
        TextView detailCmRow_comment;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: use Collections.reverse, search Stack for it, you can find best solution

Comment: @Farrokh, thanks dear but can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to reverse your list where you set adaptor

```
Collections.reverse(yourList);
```

Comment: just your code after `commentsModel.addAll(postResponse.getComments());` and before `commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reverse()` method from `Collections`

```
Collections.reverse(your_list);
your_recyclerview.setAdapter(your_list);
```